# Consumer choice; harmful environmental aspects of polyethylene vs polypropylene

Tags: everyday-chemistry

What is the difference between polyethylene and polypropylene in terms of their aspects which are harmful to the environment during manufacture and disposal.

Comment: Define "better" and "environment", e.g. criteria to compare plastics and where they are going to be used.

Comment: Recycled glass containers like soft drink and milk bottles of old.

Comment: Obviously the one which is technically better suited for the application, because you need less of it.

Comment: @andselisk I made an edit to the question, then noticed your comment. I didn't mean to circumvent your question. The word "better" can be a "downvote attractor", so I sometimes try to rescue a new user from too many of them.

Answer (score 2):

Every material is terrible if not properly collected and processed after use.

Wether you re-use it (like glass bottles), or recycle the material, or burn it to make electricity and district heating, is small potatoes.

What material you use is also not very important, only the actual energy and environmental costs of "bio"materials like paper or cotton are very high. You have to re-use them very often before they make sense!